# followers and following sytem

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, social-media

I am working on a social network web application I have established a system of following followers with firebase and node js , so I created a collection users and in it two following followers array, I managed to add them
Now I want to issue a condition to check if the user has already made a follow up not to add it a second time to the table how can i access to the tables (following, followers)in order to verify if the user is in

```
exports.onFollow = (req, res) => {
    const followDocument = db.doc(`/users/${req.body.email}`);
    const followerDocument = db.doc(`/users/${req.user.email}`);
    let followData;
    let followerData;

    followDocument
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          followData = doc.data();

          if ('req.user.email', 'in', followData.followers.docs) {
            return res.status(200).json({
              error: 'user already follow'
            });
          } else {
            followData.followers.push(req.user.email);
            return followDocument.update({
              followers: followData.followers
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err.code
        });
      });
```

Comment: What's this `if ('req.user.email', 'in', followData.followers.docs)` ?? That is not correct syntax. Learn javascript first before trying more difficult stuff.

Comment: i want to verify if the email is already present in the followers array because i want followers to be an array with unique values . how can i verify this ??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `followers` to be an array with unique values, so that each email address can only occurs once. Firestore has  special `arrayUnion` operation for adding values to such a field.

From the documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

> If your document contains an array field, you can use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` to add and remove elements. `arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array but only elements not already present. `arrayRemove()` removes all instances of each given element.
>
> ```
> var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");
>
> // Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
> washingtonRef.update({
>    regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
> });
>
> // Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
> washingtonRef.update({
>    regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
> });
> ```

I'd recommend switching to using `arrayUnion()` for your use-case, as it prevents having to do the query to detect if the email address is already in the array.